# Calculate amount of FLOPs for an eigenvalue problem solver

Tags: computational-complexity, eigenvalues, flips-flops

I've got 2 complex, non symmetric, matrices $A_{1000x1000}$, $B_{1000x1000}$ and I am using Matlab to get it's eigenvalues (functions like eig or eigs). Both matrices are different - one is more dense and the other one has more complex values. To compare the complexity of the eigenvalue solving process for both matrices I would like to calculate the amount of FLOPs needed for this procedure. Ofcourse it is possible to calculate the time need for the eigenvalue solver to complete it's task, but this is highly unstable, since a lot of background processes might be creating some noise.

In Matlab there is no function that would allow me to get FLOPs for *eigs* but I might use an other software, since the only thing I need are these matrices $A,B$ which can be exportet. Does anyone have an Idea how I could reach my goal?

Comment: You should ask this at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ rather than here.

Comment: ok thanks, then I will post the question there. Sorry for the wrong post. Admin, please close this topic